# Getting data from WebAPI and loading it in dropdown using AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to load dropdown from database, don't know what causes the problem but can't see it loaded or returned from webservice.

I created a separate webapi project and when I call the api method directly from my browser it does reutrn a data in JSON format as below

```
    <ArrayOfGetCustomersList_Result xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Repository">
<GetCustomersList_Result>
<cust_name>Alex Fraser Group : Alex Fraser</cust_name>
<custid>Alex Fraser</custid>
<customer_auto>24</customer_auto>
</GetCustomersList_Result>
<GetCustomersList_Result>
<cust_name>BMA : BMA</cust_name>
<custid>BMA</custid>
<customer_auto>16</customer_auto>
</GetCustomersList_Result>
<GetCustomersList_Result>
<cust_name>DEMO CUSTOMER 1 : DEMO CUSTOMER 1</cust_name>
<custid>DEMO CUSTOMER 1</custid>
<customer_auto>1</customer_auto>
</GetCustomersList_Result>
<GetCustomersList_Result>
<cust_name>Hydraulink Toowoomba : Hydraulink Toowoomba</cust_name>
<custid>Hydraulink Toowoomba</custid>
<customer_auto>21</customer_auto>
</GetCustomersList_Result>
<GetCustomersList_Result>
<cust_name>QA Trackspares : QA Trackspares</cust_name>
<custid>QA Trackspares</custid>
<customer_auto>22</customer_auto>
</GetCustomersList_Result>
<GetCustomersList_Result>
<cust_name>Timms Contracting : Timms</cust_name>
<custid>Timms</custid>
<customer_auto>23</customer_auto>
</GetCustomersList_Result>
<GetCustomersList_Result>
<cust_name>UNKNOWN : UNKNOWN</cust_name>
<custid>UNKNOWN</custid>
<customer_auto>17</customer_auto>
</GetCustomersList_Result>
</ArrayOfGetCustomersList_Result>
```

My Angular Service code is:

```
var app = angular.module('dashboardModule', ['oc.lazyLoad', 'directive.contextMenu'])
.service('dashboardService', ['$http', function ($http) {

    this.loadCustomers = function (onSuccess, onError) {

        onError = onError || function () { alert('Failure getting customers'); };
        $http
            .get('http://localhost:7999/api/dashboard/GetCustomersList')
            .success(onSuccess)
            .error(onError);
    };

}]);
```

I'm calling this from my Angular controller as:

```
angular.module('dashboardModule')
        .controller('dashboardController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$location', '$translate', 'dashboardService', function ($scope, $rootScope, $location, $translate, dashboardService) {

        $scope.customers = [];
        dashboardService.loadCustomers(customersLoaded,erroroccured);

        function erroroccured(response)
        {
            alert(response.data);
        }
        function customersLoaded(response) {
            $scope.customers=response.data;
        }

        $scope.selectedCustomer = $scope.customers[0].customer_auto;
    }
]);
```

and on my html page i'm trying to load it as

```
<div class="col-sm-2"><select class="form-control" ng-model="selectedCustomer" ng-options="customer.customer_auto as (customer.custid+':'+customer.cust_name) for customer in customers">></select></div>
```

can somebody tell me what's the issue in the code. I do get this error in IE debugger

> Unable to get property 'customer_auto' of undefined or null reference

Answer (score 0):

If there is an issue with the ajax call it looks like it would be sending you an alert in the erroroccured method. Is it hitting the error callback method or is the server coming back successfully with data?

Also in your web api project, try adding the following: It will make your services return valid JSON instead of XML.

```html
var formatters = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters;

formatters.Remove(formatters.XmlFormatter);
```